# Javascript - error background not showing

Tags: javascript

When I run this javascript I get: `Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AudioPlayer</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Player"></div>
<script>
function Player() {
    this.width = '100%';
    this.height = '10px';
    this.family = 'toma';
    this.size = '10px';
    this._bg = '#00000';
    this.titleContainerWidth = '100px';
    this.alignText = 'center';
    this.titleMargin = '0 auto';
    this.titleText = 'THI IS THE TITLE';
    this.color = '#29FFFF';
    this.id = 'Player';
    this.autoplay = false;
    this.pl = document.getElementById(this.id);

    this.cadd = function(element) {
        var elemnt = document.createElement(element);
        this.pl.appendChild(elemnt);
        return elemnt
    }

    this._make = function() {
        var title = this.cadd('p');
        title.style.fontFamily = this.family;
        title.style.fontSize = this.size;
        title.style.textAlign = this.alignText;
        title.style.color = this.color;
        title.style.width = this.titleContainerWidth;
        title.style.margin = this.titleMargin;
        title.innerHTML = "<marquee behavior='scrolling' speed='1' loop='true'>" + this.titleText + "</marquee>";
        this.pl.style.width = this.width;
        this.pl.style.background = this._bg;

    }


}
player = new Player();
player._make();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What does it mean? I'm only guessing that's the reason why the background won't show for the div id. But, I'm not sure. Could it be how I call the div in javascript, or the title?

Comment: The code you posted is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: that's everything besides the html tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS hex colours have a hash followed by either three or six characters. Yours has five.

Comment: I see I didn't know it was strict like that, problem solved.